# How to mock an Exception on a get-property with Moq

Tags: c#, nunit, moq

I have a getter only property like

```
public ICar Car
{
  { 
    get 
    {
      return _car ?? (_car = GetCar());
    }
  }
}
```

`GetCar()` will throw `NotSupportedException` under certain circumstances and I want to unit test this.  I am using Moq.

I am trying to use this in my unit test but it does not work on properties, only on methods

```
var sut = new CarProcessor(...); //init subject under test
Assert.Throws<NotSupportedException>(() => sut.Car); //evaluate result of Car property
```

This wont compile and it says **"Only assignment call, increment, decrement, await and new object expression can be used as a statement"** error.

Doing same as above for a method instead property works fine.

Comment: Can you mock GetCar?  ie. is GetCar() public or protected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work around this by assigning the property in a statement lambda, like so:

```
Assert.Throws<NotSupportedException>(() => { var _ = sut.Car; });
```

This will attempt to assign the property to a throwaway variable `_` (C# 7+ only, use `x` if you're compiling against a a lower language level), which should compile just fine.